# Is there any API Gateway for Azure AKS (Azure kubernetes services) cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, api-gateway, azure-aks

I am new to AKS. I am planning to deploy Micro Services using AKS cluster (Azure kubernetes services) on Azure platform and I want to secure it with solid Authentication and Authorization with Azure AD support. To Do this I am looking for best suited API gateway which supports kubernetes i.e. AKS

API gateway should have following feature -

```
    1. Authentication and Authorization support
    2. Azure Active directory integration
    3. SSL termination
    4. KPI Metrics
    5. Load Balancing
    6. Request Tracing
    7. Auto scaling
    8. Pre/Post request processing
```

I have explored couple of options like Ingress Controller, Ambassador. 
Also we cannot use Azure API Management due to some restrictions from client.

Comment: What are the restrictions that preclude use of Azure APIM?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing supports all of those "in box". You can use Azure application gateway, but it wont do 1,2,6,8 (not sure what you mean by 6 exactly). You can take a look at [Istio](https://istio.io), it has got lots of features. But for tracing you'd probably need to use something like Jaeger\Zipkin.

I think you might be able to use oAuth feature of zipkin to validate oAuth token from Azure AD, but you might need to offload that piece to a service.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, Thank you.
Request Tracing means I want to trace my request while flowing through different components.
What is your view about Ambassador [https://www.getambassador.io/]

Comment: never used ambassador, sorry. request tracing can be achieved exactly as I specified in the answer